# Zend Framework Drop Down List onChange

Tags: zend-framework, html-select

I want to call a function everytime when i select/change something in my dropdown list . 
My code is like this :

```
$aar = $form->createElement ('select','id_category', array('label'=>'Category' , 'required' => true , 'multiOptions'=>$sampleArray));
$aar->setAttribs(array('style' => 'width:300px;', 'width' => '50'));
$aar->setOptions(array('onChange' => $this->go()));
```

But this is not correct because the function is called one time , when i create the Zend_Form .
Please help me , thanks !

Comment: You understand that the value of the onchange attribute can only be a javascript function, right? You can't get it to call a PHP function like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can add like this

```
$name = $this->createElement(‘select’,'name’);
$name->addMultioptions(array(

‘select’=>’[select]‘,

’1′ => ‘Faheem’,

’2′ => ‘Abbas’

));

$name->setAttrib(‘onchange’,'AutoFill(this.value)’);
```

let me know if i can help you..

Comment: Thanks for response , but this is not working . The function is not called .

Comment: have u used like  $this->formElement('select','reason');

Comment: Yes . The dropdown-list is showing , but the function is not called .

Comment: pls check your html source is generating properly